# If voltage across a capacitor GROWS till maximum in finite time then, is it possible that the capacitor also reaches maximum charge in finite time?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, voltage

[image: the image is description of voltage, i am talking about]

When a dc-voltage `V` is applied to a capacitor `C`, the charge on it takes infinite time to reach maximum value `CV`, but if voltage across a capacitor grows till maximum in finite time like:

```
V(t) = V0 × sin(omega × t), t < T / 4;
V(t) = V0, t >= T / 4;
T is the time period;
graph of V in image
```

then, is it possible that the capacitor also reaches maximum charge in finite time?

because, here capacitor at any moment will need grow only a infinitesimal value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your idea, you assume that the capacitor is charged into a circuit without resistance. In this case, the charging time $RC$ is zero and the circuit is charged instantaneously.

${{V}_{0}}=RC\frac{d{{v}_{s}}}{dt}+{{v}_{s}}$ give ${{v}_{s}}(t)={{V}_{0}}(1-{{e}^{-t/RC}})$ grows instantaneously if $RC$ is zero.

${{V}_{0}}\sin (\omega t)=RC\frac{d{{v}_{s}}}{dt}+{{v}_{s}}$ give ${{v}_{s}}(t)=\frac{{{V}_{0}}}{\sqrt{1+{{(RC\omega )}^{2}}}}\left( \sin (\omega t-\varphi )+\sin (\varphi ){{e}^{-t/RC}} \right)$ with $\varphi =\arctan \left( RC\omega  \right)$

You can see that there is a phase delay between the two voltages.

Comment: thnx, this worked for me :)